# Parallel hashing function that always gives the same hash despite a variable number of cpus

Tags: hash

The title pretty much sums it up :)

I'm looking for a hashing algorithm that does not need to be cryptographically secure beyond reducing the number of accidental collisions. There is no need to protect against a determined attacker.

Naively I thought I could take a file, cut it up into 1Gb chunks, hash each chunk individually, then hash the concatenation of the chunk hashes, as detail in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015544/calculating-a-hash-code-for-a-large-file-in-parallel/36201575

This gives consistent hashes, however there is no relationship between the number of free processors, and the number of chunks. This is a shame, because you might have 100 cpus and you want to hash a 50Gb file, but you will only be 50% efficient. Alternatively, you might have 1 cpu and 100Gb file, and now there's overhead for making 100 1Gb chunks, hashing chunks, concatenating hashes, hashing again, etc, when the most efficient thing to do would be to just hash the file in 1 go.

So im looking for an algorithm that will essentially use up all my processors, but always give the same hash for the same data, irrespective of the number of processors used. Thank you so much!!

Comment: "now there's overhead for making 100 1Gb chunks, hashing chunks, concatenating hashes, hashing again" -- the overhead is negligible.

Comment: Polynomial hashes (GHash, Poly1305) would work. Such hashes are only collision resistant against attackers who don't know the key, and 128 bits is a bit on the small side, even without attackers. A Xor-MAC like (the patented) OCB mode uses for its authenticated data has similar properties.

Comment: An alternative to CodesInChaos's suggestion of a polynomial hash (which I was also going to mention) is to compute the CRC of the file; CRC's can be computed in parallel as well

Comment: I think you can always use a tree hash with relatively small nodes. In that case you can always ask a worker to do more than one node at a time in case the calculation is inefficient. That is; if you stick with a regular, secure hash. Otherwise the algorithmic solutions of Poncho & CodesInChaos may be preferred.